# method initLoader issue

Tags: java, android, events, compiler-errors

In class MainActivity,java:

```
  public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements 
  LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

public void onClickBtnDispNames(View view) {
    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);
}
}
```

there is an error:

```
The method initLoader(int, Bundle, LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<D>) in the type LoaderManager is    
 not applicable for the arguments (int, null, MainActivity)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you import `LoaderManager` and related classes from the same `android.support.v4.*` package.

```
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the error is that you are importing `android.app.LoaderManager` and `getSupportLoaderManager` is looking for a `android.support.v4.LoaderManager` class.